# Почему не добавляется класс для body в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.header_hamburger').click(function(){
  $('.sidebar').addClass('active');
  $('body').addClass('ov-hid');
});

$('.header_close').click(function(){
  $('.sidebar').removeClass('active');
  $('body').removeClass('ov-hid');
});
```

Comment: А событие клика точно отрабатывает? 
`$('body').addClass('ov-hid');` - работает, я проверил

Comment: Для sidebar все отрабатывается, класс добавляется и удаляется при клике. Для body почему-то нет. Т.е.  при клике у body появляется слово class, но сам класс не добавляется

Comment: @Семен добавь html код

Comment: @Семен как вариант, если он добавляет атрибут класса, но не добавляет класс - может он добавляет, но какое то другое событие его удаляет тут же.

Comment: Да, другая функция блокировала добавление класса